# IBM Worklight - Unable to locate .xap file for Windows 8 tablet

Tags: windows-8, ibm-mobilefirst

I am currently running a IBM Worklight project which supports Windows 8 (tablet).

Can you please let me know where is the location of the .xap file for Windows 8 on the system? I am able to find it for Windows Phone 8 in bin folder but for tablet it is not appearing. please share some sample location.

Comment: Please clarify if you are talking about the Windows Phone 8 environment or the Windows 8 environment. I have edited the question but I am not entirely sure about what you meant.

Comment: Hi Idan, I am referring to window8 envrionment for tablet which we create in IBM Worklight, i am try to locate the binary or .xap file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generated binary for a Windows 8 app is not .xap; rather, it is **.appx** AFAICT.

To create it, in Visual Studio: `Project >> Store >> Create App Packages...`
You can then choose to either login to your Windows Store account or generate it for local use. Follow the provided wizard.

The path to the package will be provided by the wizard.

---

General notes about mobile environments in Worklight (Android, BlackBerry 6/7/10, iOS, Windows 8/Pro/RT and Windows Phone 8):

- Worklight NEVER generates the final artifact, be it .cod, .bar, .apk, .ipa, .xap or .appx
- This is done by the respective tools of the environments, that is: Ripple, ADT, Xcode and Visual Studio 2012
- For more information, [consult with the IBM Worklight Getting Started training materials](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/library/)

Comment: Hi Idan, create app packages is disabled. Also i serach for appx in my folders and i am getting a list of files named appxrecipe...is that the one i need to use. location  C:\Users\266074\Desktop\24th july\23rd\Test_Login\apps\Test\windows8\native\bin\Debug\AppX

Comment: See here: http://www.fan-fictions.com/site/extension/how-do-i-open-a-appx.html - I don't know why it's disabled, but the way I described is the way to do it.

Comment: @djrecker if your question is answered, please mark as Answered.